# How to download email with PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to write a very simple web-based email client from scratch with PHP's standard library. I'll be honest; I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, so this is something that I hacked together for trial-and-error learning. However, I keep timing out no matter what I try. Any advice? I know the intended output won't look pretty, but like I said, this is just for trial and error.

```
<?php

$stream = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', '<email_removed>', '<password_removed>') or
    die('Cannot connect to server: ' . imap_last_error());

$date = date('d M Y', strtotime('-1 month'));
if ($emails = imap_search($stream, "SINCE \"$date\"")) {
    rsort($emails);

    foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
        echo imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_number, 2);
    }
}

imap_close($stream);

?>
```

The output I get it as follows.

**Warning**: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in  on line 3
Cannot connect to server: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Network is unreachable

**Notice**: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

**Notice**: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

**Notice**: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Network is unreachable (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: `Network is unreachable` generally implies you can't get _any_ outbound network.

Comment: Can your machine route to `gmail-imap.l.google.com`? Is your webserver confined with a  [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)?

Comment: @sarnold, I'm not sure. How can I find that out?

Comment: Try something like: `ping gmail-imap.l.google.com` or `telnet gmail-imap.l.google.com imaps` or `openssl s_client -connect gmail-imap.l.google.com:imaps`.

Comment: @sarnold ping is disabled on my server, the telnet command timed out as did the openssl command.

Comment: Excellent! Now you know what you need to do -- figure out why your server cannot make outbound connections to these hosts. Can you make outbound connections to _any_ hosts? Figure out which ones are allowed and denied. You may need to fiddle with your system's firewall or get your host's admins to fiddle with their firewalls. If this is an EC2 instance, you'll need to modify group policy.

Comment: @sarnold, figured out that my host disallows it. They seem to not budge for any requested changes to the server. So I'm SOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, my host (HostMonster) [disallows this](http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4640), so I will have to take my business elsewhere. :/

Comment: Bluehost apparently also dissables it

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, I believe that they are owned by the same company.